# Using Playa to display fixed and then random entries

Tags: playa, loop, random

I'm using Playa to display entries in a "Featured Stories" list.  Let's say I have ten stories selected in the Playa.  I'd like to be able to control the first three featured stories in the order they appear in Playa but the other seven should come next in random order.

Is this possible in one loop?  Something like:

```
{playa-featured-stories}

  {stuff}

 {if "{count}" > "3" sort="random"} 

  {stuff} 

 {/if}

{/playa-featured-stories}
```

which obviously doesn't work

I suppose I could use two loops and target entries 1-3 and 4-10 separately but feel like there is a cleaner solution that I am missing?

Comment: I think your idea of separate loops is best. You could also look at the SQL a loop generates and edit that, but that's a lot of work. Or, you could push the results in to Stash array and work from there, but again, probably more work than it's worth.